# Adding duration value from one column to the latest date in another column grouped by customers

Tags: mysql

I have a customer contract_table in my database with customer_id, contract_duration (in months) and invoice_date. I'd like to to add the duration to the latest invoice date grouped by customer.

```
 customer_id  invoice_date  duration
           1    2016-01-01        12
           1    2017-01-01         6     
           2    2016-02-01        24
           3    2014-03-01        24
           3    2016-03-01         3
```

The desired output would be

```
 customer_id  contract_end
           1    2017-07-01
           2    2018-02-01  
           3    2016-05-01
```

I tried the following, which is not working. Up front I thought MySQL would use the duration value corresponding to the MAX(invoice_date). Is there a quick way to get the above result?

```
SELECT customer_id, MAX(invoice_date) + INTERVAL duration MONTH 
FROM contract_table
GROUP BY customer_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this select:

```
SELECT customer_id, MAX(d) AS contract_end FROM (
    SELECT
    customer_id,
    @num:=CAST(duration AS UNSIGNED),
    DATE_ADD(invoice_date, INTERVAL @num MONTH) AS d
    FROM my_table
) t
GROUP BY customer_id
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6913/2/0).

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your result set so I've ignored it. If my result is wrong, please try to explain why in comments...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(customer_id INT NOT NULL
,invoice_date DATE NOT NULL
,duration INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(customer_id,invoice_date)
);


INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'2016-01-01',12),
(1,'2017-01-01',6),
(2,'2016-02-01',24),
(3,'2014-03-01',24),
(3,'2016-03-01',3);

SELECT a.*
     , a.invoice_date + INTERVAL a.duration MONTH contract_end
  FROM my_table a
  JOIN
     ( SELECT customer_id
            , MAX(invoice_date + INTERVAL duration MONTH) x
         FROM my_table
        GROUP
           BY customer_id
     ) b
    ON b.x = a.invoice_date + INTERVAL a.duration MONTH;
+-------------+--------------+----------+--------------+
| customer_id | invoice_date | duration | contract_end |
+-------------+--------------+----------+--------------+
|           1 | 2017-01-01   |        6 | 2017-07-01   |
|           2 | 2016-02-01   |       24 | 2018-02-01   |
|           3 | 2016-03-01   |        3 | 2016-06-01   |
+-------------+--------------+----------+--------------+
```